Creating animal movement correlated random paths within a state boundary in R program
First time poster here, I'm hoping that someone could help me figure this out. I am trying to create "correlated random paths" that simulate real animal movements based on actual data within an entire state boundary. The data will then be used to extract environmental covariates for modeling purposes. I have tried using the sf, move, and adehabitat packages in R and have also referenced the package example along with the Fletcher and Fortin (2018, found here: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-01989-1) resource selection chapter for this, however, some of the following issues have occurred:

The data is extensive for running simulations within a large state, sometimes the program crashes when trying to execute this or it just takes forever to run.

The simulations do not occur within the boundary and run outside the boundary intended.



These are the packages I've been using throughout if it helps:

library(dplyr); 
library(raster); 
library(sf); 
library(sp); 
library(mapview); 
library(lubridate); 
library(tidyverse); 
library(adehabitatLT); 
library(adehabitatHR) 


Here is an example of code I have tried from the adehabitat package. I have also tried the example from Fletcher and Fortin 2018 resource selection chapter. For the random paths, I am wanting the simulations to be entirely random but based on the actual turning angles and step distances and not just rotated on the "barycenter". Here is a snippet of the overall data I'm using:
animal.id   timestamp              lat            long

1          2019-09-22 16:03       43.44296      -105.8370
1          2019-09-29 16:23       43.47755      -105.8217
2          2019-08-31 09:18       41.44881      -109.8222


ADEHABITAT EXAMPLE
data(animal_data)

#sets up a raster boundary with elevation tiff, and converts to a spatial pixel data frame
par <- raster("D:/R/ELEV_30.tif")
par <- as(par, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")

#animal data is all animals, with individual id's for different ones
myfunc <- function(animal_data, par)
consfun <- function(animal_data, par)
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))

#plot boundary, create new object
image(par)
map <- par
lines(animal_data[,1], animal_data[,2], lwd=2)
rxy <- apply(coordinates(par),2,range)
coordinates(animal_data) <- animal_data[,1:2]

#format time column and create a ltraj object
animal_data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(animal_data$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
animal.final <- animal_data %>%   
  mutate(timestamp = force_tz(timestamp, "UTC"))

animal.traj <- as.ltraj(xy = animal_data[,c('long', 'lat')], date = animal_data[,'timestamp'], id = animal_data[,'animal.id'],
typeII = TRUE,
infolocs = animal_data[,c(1,2)])

#this should create the "correlated random path" with ten random iterations that include the functions previously made

animal.CRW <- NMs.randomCRW(animal.traj, rangles=TRUE, rdist=TRUE, fixedStart = TRUE,
x0 = NULL, rx = NULL, ry = NULL,
treatment.func = myfunc,
treatment.par = map, constraint.func =consfun,
constraint.par = map, nrep=10)

#then plot animal data within the raster boundary

plot.ltraj(animal.traj)
plot.ltraj(animal.CRW)
par(mfrow = c(3,3))
tmp <- testNM(animal.CRW)

#create dataframe of new iterations
write.csv(animal.CRW, file = "random path.csv", row.names = FALSE)

Any help with this to provide clarity or an example that restricts the animal movement iterations to within the boundary is incredibly appreciated, thank you!
Note: Can an "if" statement be used for this kind of code to restrict R from having simulations go outside of the boundary intended?
Update: I have tried the code for the "hab" package (here: https://github.com/basille/hab),
and ran into this error:
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'coordinates': cannot allocate vector of size 16.0 Gb
Is this an issue that can be solved with increasing the computer's ram, or is it something else entirely? One of my animal's location data frames consist of roughly 1600 points and I want to try this for all animals that I have (data is approximately 64000 locations). Just trying one animal though, R throws that error or crashes.

(1) It's generally better to have everything you need within the question, please [edit] your question to add that other line of code. (2) While it seems to be mostly aesthetic, formatting a question well can make a big difference getting people to look at your problem. Please read about [code block]s and how to get all of the "code/comments" as fixed-width code-block formatting in your question. The easiest is likely to highlight your code blocks and press Ctrl-K, though that's not the only. (This includes your calls to library(..), should be ;-separated or \n-separated.)

(3) Also, please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., data.frame(...) or the output from dput(head(x))) directly into a [code block].

FYI, there is a lot of code here, and it seems like this is "help with many problems". It's generally better to choose one problem and provide the minimum code and sample-data to reproduce that one problem. Having a large question like this can be intimidating, and many of us are "drive-by answerers": often, if I have just a few moments, I'll look at questions, and for those that will clearly take much more time, I'll just leave (and likely not come back for various reasons). I'm not saying "hard problems" cannot be asked here, just trying to help you get some help. Good luck!

Thanks for the feedback @r2evans, I trimmed down the question to just include the first example and tried to format the code to what was recommended. Hope that helps for clarity.

Not entirely, but closer, thanks. See my edit for what I was thinking; if it is not what you want we can easily rollback my edit (with my apologies).

@r2evans, no it really helped. My first stack post even though I've perused this forum for years, so I figured there would be some issues with figuring out the formatting for questions, much appreciated!
